# Object.defineProperty in Node.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am running the following code in a browser console and also with `node.js v9.11.1` in the terminal:

```
let name = {};
Object.defineProperty(name, 'last', {value: 'Doe'});
console.log(name);
```

The browser console works properly and outputs `{ last: 'Doe' }`. But in the terminal with `node.js`, it fails and outputs a blank object, `{}`.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Found this https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/798 when I googled your question title.

Comment: Thanks @Chris G. Nice pointer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the properties of property descriptors is `enumerable`, which has the default value `false`. If a property is non-enumerable, Node.js chooses not to display the property, thats it.

You can change that bit and try this

```js
let name = {};
Object.defineProperty(name, 'last', {
  value: 'Doe',
  enumerable: true
});
console.log(name);
```

Comment: i was typing this as the answer came up heh.  yes.  youll notice if you repl without setting `enumerable` to true, you can `console.log(name.last)` and it will output 'Doe' as expected in node.

Comment: Wonderful! These are all great responses. My desire was to use the object with the `Spread operator` like `{...name}` in one of my operations. So the `enumerable: true` bit has sorted me out. Thank you @thefourtheye and @James LeClair!

Comment: @JohnMutuma: FWIW, [`...` is not an operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)